# check if string contains number and return the number

Tags: python, string, integer

I'm using python and I have a string variable `foo = " I have 1 kilo of tomatoes "`
What I want is to check if my string contains an integer (in our case 1 ) and return the specific integer 
I know I can use the isdigit function like :

```
def hashnumbers(inputString):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)
```

But it returns true or false and does not store the number . 
I would appreciate your help . Thank you in advance .

Comment: If there is no digit, what do you want to return ?

Comment: @azro I want to return the 1 from the string foo I have above and store it in a variable

Comment: What about when there is **NO** digit in the given string, what to return ? False ?

Comment: @azro I just want to check if a number exists in the string and if it does store it in a variable and return it

Comment: What if there are multiple digits in the given string? For instance foo = "I have 1 kilo of tomatoes and 10kg of potatoes"

Comment: @rakeb.mazharul In my example I only need 1 digit

Comment: @azro Return null or zero ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `List Comprehension` : Return the digits

   To return the digits, use a list comprehension with  `if`

   ```
   def hashnumbers(inputString):
       return [char for char in inputString if char.isdigit()]

   print(hashnumbers("super string"))    # []
   print(hashnumbers("super 2 string"))  # ['2']
   print(hashnumbers("super 2 3 string")) # ['2', '3']
   ```
2. Return a default value if no digits found (empty list is evaluated as False)

   ```
   return [char for char in inputString if char.isdigit()] or None
   ```
3. Regex version with `re.findall`

   ```
   return re.findall(r"\d", inputString) 
   return re.findall(r"\d", inputString) or None
   ```
4. Return **first one** only

   ```
   def hashnumbers(inputString):
       return next((char for char in inputString if char.isdigit()), None)

   print(hashnumbers("super string"))    # None
   print(hashnumbers("super 2 string"))  # 2
   print(hashnumbers("super 2 3string")) # 2
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Using list comprehension however , if your number is 10 you get ['1' , '0'] . How could the function be edited to return 2 digit number ? Thanks again

Comment: @VasilisSkentos `re.findall(r"\d+", inputString)`

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little unclear, but I've assumed the following:

- You want your function to **return** true or false. Not a number
- You want the function to **print** any numbers in the string

If that's right, this code should work:

```
def hashnumbers(inputString):
    num = False
    for i in inputString:
        if i.isdigit():
            num = True
            print(i)
    return num
```

However, if I've misunderstood what functionality you're looking for, let me know and I'll amend this.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much . It is very helpful . What I wanted was to return the integer

Comment: No problem at all :)